# Can I disable or delete the AWS managed keys in AWS KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-kms, key-management

When I checked the AWS KMS, in the **AWS managed keys** section I had a key "**aws/rds**" which is enabled. Can I delete or atleast disable that(AWS managed) key?
Else when will that key be disabled automatically?
Also will I be charged for it since it's status is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't disable them. They are AWS Managed, which means AWS manages them, not you.

If you want to manage your keys, you have to create Customer Managed Key.